# Magento Admin login page is not loading

Tags: magento

I have transferred the Magento site to another domain, Front end is working fine. But when I try to login to my admin panel then then it shows blank page. I have un-comment this line

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

from index.php but it does not show any error.

Comment: Look into your error_log file. Most likely the username of the another domain is different, which means that absolute paths are most likely different. You should really look into error log for more information.

Comment: But I can't access to magento admin, So how can I see the error_log file from FTP?

Comment: Error log is in the ftp, but where it is located, depends on the hosting configuration. You might even be able to see errors directly in cPanel (if you have cPanel), or in the same folder where the file with error is located (i.e. if .php file is in /admin/ folder then error_log should be in /admin/ folder too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In index.php file, you can try enabling magento developer mode to exactly figure out what the error is. In index.php find the code that says:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

now edit this so that the code reads:

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

This should enable developer mode and error should be displayed.